# Azure Devops / Loop and Display all template parameters in single bash script

Tags: azure-devops

Template parameters can be displayed in this way.  With one parameter per script:

```
- ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
  - script: echo ${{ parameter.Key }}
```

How to iterate through parameters and display them all within a single script instead?

EDIT: I forgot to specify:

- I want to display parameter name and the value passed to template
- Multiple parameters passed, not a single parameter of type array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [join expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#join) to convert the parameter to string and output its value: See below example:

```
parameters:
- name: myArray
  type: object
  default:
    - FOO
    - BAR
    - ZOO

variables:
   A: ${{ join(';',parameters.myArray) }}

steps:
  - script: echo "$(A)" # outputs FOO;BAR;ZOO
```

Update:

I am afraid there is not direct way to display the multiple parameters' names and values. However, you can check below workaround to use [Pipeline preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/preview/preview?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api. So that you can see all the parameters in a single task. See below example in powershell script:

```
- powershell: |
   $url ="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/pipelines/$(System.DefinitionId)/preview?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
   $body="{'previewRun': 'true'}"
   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.accesstoken)"} -Method post  -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
   $result.finalYaml
```

Comment: I have multiple parameters, not one of type array.  I edited question to specify I need to display a list of parameter names and the value for each.

Comment: @jhurtas I am afraid there is not an easy way to achieve this. I have a workaround using Pipeline- Preview rest api. See above update:

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it working correctly, here is the full snippets that is working at my side

```html
parameters:
- name: param1
  type: string
  default: okay
- name: testq
  type: string
  default: 222
- name: myArray
  type: object
  default:
    - FOO
    - BAR
    - ZOO

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- ${{ each setup in parameters }}:
  - script: echo ${{ setup.key }}  value ${{ convertToJson( join(';',setup.value)) }}
```

`
here is the output of the pipeline [screenshot of azure pipeline log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxQo8.png)